# How to consume ASP.NET Web API 2.0 with bearer token via a desktop/console application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, authentication, asp.net-web-api

I have a console/winform (non-browser) application that consumes an ASP.NET Web API. I have implemented a token based authentication to secure my web api and need to find out where is the best place to retrieve the token given that I have followed a repository pattern using a `HttpClientHelper` class?

To Get the token:

```
private static string GetToken(string url, string userName, string password)
{
    var pairs = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>( "grant_type", "password" ), 
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>( "username", userName ), 
        new KeyValuePair<string, string> ( "Password", password )
    };

    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(pairs);

    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

    using(var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var response = client.PostAsync(url + "Token", content).Result;
        return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    }
}
```

HttpClient Helper:

```
public sealed class HttpClientHelper<T, TResourceIdentifier> : IDisposable where T : class
{
        #region Constructors

        public HttpClientHelper(string serviceBaseAddress, string addressSuffix, string token)
        {
            _serviceBaseAddress = serviceBaseAddress;
            _addressSuffix = addressSuffix;
            _token = token
            _httpClient = MakeHttpClient();
        }

        #endregion

        #region CRUD

        public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetManyAsync()
        {
            var responseMessage = await _httpClient.GetAsync(_addressSuffix);

            if (responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                return await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<T>>();

            return null;
        }

        // Other CRUD operations

        #endregion

        #region Private Methods

        private HttpClient MakeHttpClient()
        {
            _httpClient = new HttpClient
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri(_serviceBaseAddress),
                MaxResponseContentBufferSize = int.MaxValue,
                DefaultRequestHeaders = {Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", token)}
            };

            // Other settings

            return _httpClient;
        }

        #region IDisposable Members

        private void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (_disposed || !disposing) return;

            if (_httpClient != null)
            {
                var hc = _httpClient;
                _httpClient = null;
                hc.Dispose();
            }

            _disposed = true;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        ~HttpClientHelper()
        {
            Dispose(false);
        }

        #endregion IDisposable Members
    }
}
```

My generic class:

```
internal class GenericRepository<T, TResourceIdentifier> : IDisposable, IGenericRepository<T, TResourceIdentifier>  where T : class
{
    private bool _disposed;
    protected HttpClientHelper<T, TResourceIdentifier> Client;

    protected GenericRepository(string serviceBaseAddress, string addressSuffix, string token)
    {
        Client = new HttpClientHelper<T, TResourceIdentifier>(serviceBaseAddress, addressSuffix, token);
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetManyAsync()
    {
        return await Client.GetManyAsync();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (_disposed || !disposing) return;

        if (Client != null)
        {
            var mc = Client;
            Client = null;
            mc.Dispose();
        }

        _disposed = true;
    }
}
```

Custom repository class example:

```
internal class CustomerRepository : GenericRepository<Customer, int> , ICustomerRepository
{
    internal CustomerRepository() : base(Properties.Settings.Default.Url, "Customers/", ***TOKEN***)
    {
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
private readonly ICustomerRepository _customerRepository = new CustomerRepository();

private async Task<Customer> GetCustomer(int customerId)   
{
    var customer = new Customer();

    try
    {
        customer = await _customerRepository.GetAsync(customerId);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Log the error
    }

    return customer;
}
```

Where exactly do I get/assigne the token without getting nullexception error at the declaration of my IRepository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not instanciate a new `HttpClient` each time in any case. The `IDisposable` might make you think you should, but it's an anti pattern. Check https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/330364/should-we-create-a-new-single-instance-of-httpclient-for-all-requests for a lot of resources on the matter.

Same thing with token. Use your token as long as it is active. Security concerns for usage should be resolved by the identity provider and the timeout. That's why there is a refresh token to handle token expiration.

https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/refresh-token/

Comment: Good point about the usage of HttpClient and I am not. As for getting and assigning the token in the right place, I am still not sure where to do this. I have updated my post to reflect what I have added since. Any suggestion as to where (obviously in the form constructor is not the right place because I get a NullReferenceException when I initialize my repositories), I get the token and assign it?